# Expected 0 arguments but got 1. ts(2554) - abortController.abort(reason)

Tags: typescript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) `abortController.abort()` accepts one optional argument. TypeScript thinks this is wrong. Which side is right?

(Isn't there a tag for MDN Web Docs?)

Comment: They may are both right.

I found a open issue here 
https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1462#issuecomment-1019391557, it could be a version problem